# storing datetime2 in ssis variable

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis

I'm using `SQL Server 2012 Enterprise`. I have a requirement where I've to store data with `DATETIME2` datatype in SSIS Variable. Unfortunately, SSIS variables don't have that data type.

If I'm storing it into `datetime` data type, I'm losing information. Can anyone help in giving workaround?

PS: My source system is SQL Server 2012 as well and I'm reading the data from column with datetime2 datatype.

Comment: I dont know about `SSIS variables`... can you try that, store the `datetime2` as `varchar` or `string` in SSIS.? If did, then you can convert varchar to datetime2 in SQL Server.

Comment: what are you losing exactly? It is DateTime format from (.Net Framework)

Comment: Looks like `DT_DBTIMESTAMP2` should work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/integration-services-data-types

Comment: Depends what you mean by "store". When in a dataflow task, then @PeterB is correct, you want `DT_DBTIMESTAMP2`. If you're declaring a variable, however, then you only have the option of `datetime`. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-ssis-variables?view=sql-server-2017) doesn't state what value types are available, however, the `DateTime` datatype is equivilent to a `datetime2(0)`.

Comment: If you need a higher scale you are (unfortunately) forced to use the string datatype, or convert your datetime is an numerical and work with that. For example, maybe you'll store `2018-12-28 09:06:34.123456` as `20181229090634.123456` or maybe `599303194123456000` (number of nanoseconds between `2000-01-01` and the date). It is a known "shortfall" of SSIS when working with its variables.

Comment: @PeterB : I need to store in `ssis variable`. It doesn't have DT_DBTIMESTAMP2

Comment: @Larnu : thanks. I don't know what `datetime2(0)` means as it is still returning datetime. Anyway, please put up your comment as answer so I can close it down !

Comment: @PrabhatG I'm a bit "concerned" you don't know what a `datetime2(0)` is, considering you mention `datetime2` in the title of your question. `datetime` <> `datetime2`. A `datetime` is accurate to `1/300` of a second, where as a `datetime2(x)` is accurate to `1/(1*10^x)` of a second.

Comment: @Larnu : I'm familiar with `datetime2`. I wasn't sure about `(0)`. After you mentioned, I checked up msdn regarding `(x)` precision. A man keeps learning SQL ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSIS, at least currently, has a "known" shortfall in that the variable value type, `DateTime` only has a precision to the second; effectively the same as a `datetime2(0)`. If you therefore need to store anything more accurate that a second, such as if you are using `datetime` and the 1/300 of a second is important or if you are using `datetime2` with a precision of 1 or more, the value type `DateTime`, will not serve your goal.

A couple of different options are therefore to store the value of as a `String` or numerical value. This does, however, come with it's own problems; most and foremost that neither of these datatypes are date and time datatypes.

It therefore depends what your goal is. I would most likely make use of a `String` datatype and ensure it has the ISO format (`'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn'`). If you're then using something like a T-SQL Task you can pass your variable as normal to the task and the data engine will interpret the literal string as a `datetime2(7)` (or whichever literal precision you used).